# Can I use a derivative work of an editorial image for commercial purpose?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, copyright

I want to use an editorial (image which cannot be used for commercial purpose) image which contains a celebrity and crest of the sports team.

I've use Photoshop filters to create a water-paint effect photo. The face of the celebrity is completely hidden/blurred as is any crest or other identifiable data.

Can I use this derivative image for commercial purpose?

Comment: This has been asked a few times in various forms: [Is vectorizing an image copyright theft if the image is not CC/Public domain?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/5496/8708) • [Is it OK to include a stylized reproduction of a copyrighted painting in a design?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/12956/8708) • [Can I use portions of stock images for derivative works?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/935/8708) • [is it an act of copyright infringement if we changed the color of another artist's image to black and white?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/17249/8708)

Comment: To summarize all of those: get permission. Otherwise, it's not okay and you'll be asking for trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theres no such thing as "change it this much and it's okay."

Derivative work is generally not allowed without written permission.

Comment: what if the photographer gives permission for the photo by the photo is of a celebrity who cannot be contacted?

Comment: THe photographer can not transfer rights for the celebrity.